# flock command for Windows

Tags: windows

I'd like to get an exclusive lock for a file (it's for debugging purposes).

On Linux there's flock http://linux.die.net/man/1/flock

On BSD i've found lockf http://www.unix.com/man-page/FreeBSD/1/lockf/

Comment: now i've found this similar question:
http://superuser.com/questions/519389/flock-command-for-windows

Comment: the [cygwin util-linux](http://mirror.mcs.anl.gov/cygwin/release/util-linux/) package has this "flock" utility, but it's not working...

Answer (score 1):

When you call [CreateFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to open a file, just pass in `0` for `dwShareMode`.

> If this parameter is zero and `CreateFile` succeeds, the file or device cannot be shared and cannot be opened again until the handle to the file or device is closed.

Comment: I would like a ready-to-use tool, not a Win32 API function.

Comment: @eadmaster: I can't see how that would make any sense. What would the tool do? It would just hold the lock on the file until you manually closed it? (You might get better answers if you explain your outer problem. Are you trying to coordinate multiple operations that are cooperating?)