# How to use a file someway and tell host that "file's in use" via PowerShell script?

Tags: windows, powershell, script

I try to write a PowerShell script that asks user to give a video and audio name like:

```
$inputVideo = Read-Host "Video name"
$inputAudio = Read-Host "Audio name"
```

Then, before reading `inputAudio`, to prevent user to deleting video file, I want to keep my script busy with that video file, so if user try to delete that file he gets a OS prompt: "That file is in use"

How can I achieve this? Thank you.

Comment: Open the file?...

Comment: This is a way, true. But what I mean, is there another way to comminicate with a file except launch it? Like process in background.

Comment: Opening it is not necessarily the same as launching it ...

Comment: [windows 7 - How to purposefully exclusively lock a file? - Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/294826/how-to-purposefully-exclusively-lock-a-file)

Comment: I am so sorry. I didn't know the difference between "open" and "launch". I tried and it worked, thank you so much!