# How can I lock a file (make it seem like it's being used by a process), so that it cannot be deleted?

Tags: windows-10, filesystems

I need to test a scenario where an **un**installer encounters an error while trying to delete a file.

The problem is that it's a shortcut, a `.lnk` file (located in the `%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo` folder).
I can't achieve what I need through changing rights, because the uninstaller runs elevated and it **always** has rights to delete it.

Is there any tool which can simply "**hold the file busy**", so that the uninstaller process cannot delete it ? (eg: the way you can't delete an *.mp3* while it's playing in winamp...  ).

Thanks.

Comment: Did not test this, but see the answer by "marsh-wiggle": ( https://superuser.com/questions/294826/how-to-purposefully-exclusively-lock-a-file )

Comment: Not the officially accepted answer, but another wone from below DOES answer my question:https://superuser.com/a/857831/1232234.  
Thanks.