# Prevent renaming/moving file when file is open in Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

Usually with most programs, if I have a file open in that program, I can't rename/move that file (or rename/move its containing folder).

In contrast, with Notepad++, I can rename/move that file, whereupon Notepad++ then gives these error messages:

`Keep non existing file`

`The file "C:\...\XXX.txt" doesn't exist anymore.`

`Keep this file in editor?`

I often do the above accidentally. How do I stop this and change it so that Notepad++'s behavior is like other programs?

(I use Windows 11 if that matters.)

Comment: https://community.notepad-plus-plus.org/topic/20571/locking-file-from-other-editing-while-opened-in-notepad

Comment: You could probably write a Notepad++ plugin that does that https://superuser.com/questions/294826/how-to-purposefully-exclusively-lock-a-file

Comment: https://community.notepad-plus-plus.org/topic/15255/there-is-a-plugin-that-lock-open-files

Comment: https://community.notepad-plus-plus.org/topic/20571/locking-file-from-other-editing-while-opened-in-notepad/2